# Error loading admin portal in Orocommerce CE 5.0: No such file or directory for oro.css and app.js

Tags: orocommerce

I am new to Oro and I recently installed Orocommerce CE 5.2. While most of the pages seem to be working as expected, I am experiencing some issues with the admin portal. Specifically, when I try to access the portal, the page keeps loading indefinitely and I receive the following error messages:

"/var/www/oroshop/public/build/admin/css/oro.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)
"/var/www/oroshop/public/build/admin/app.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)

I see only app-modules.js under /admin/ and oro.css.scss under /admin/css

/var/www/oroshop/public/build/admin/css$ ls
oro.css.scss  oro.scss.js

/var/www/oroshop/public/build/admin$ ls
app-modules.js  configs.json  css  dynamic-imports.js  tinymce

Could you please provide me with some guidance on how to resolve this error?

Thank you for your help.

Dat

Comment: I found the answer. Some of the assets were missing during the build process. I reran it manually: sudo php bin/console oro:assets:install --env=prod. Now I can login the admin portal.